# How do I read the last modified file that contains a certain string?

Tags: python, readfile

I want to find the last modified file that contains a string using python. I have many files in my directory so comparing dates is not appealing. I am looking for a way to search the file by modified data until I hit a file containing the string I want. Or if there is a better way to do this that would be great.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. How are you going to find the latest modified files if you're not going to compare dates? How many is "many" files?

Comment: So rather of comparing dates, you want to compare the contents of every file? That doesn't sound like an improvement in efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for the last modified file in the current directory that contains the string `search_string`, you can use this code:

```
files = os.listdir(".")
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)
for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
        if search_string in f.read():
            print name
            break
```

This will first list all the files, sort them by modification time, newest first, and then iterates over the list of files to see if they contain `search_string`.

Comment: Why not to use `for name in sorted(os.listdir('.'), key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True):`? It's still readable and 2 lines shorter.

Comment: You're doing three things - getting a list of files, sorting them by descending mtime, and iterating over them. It's more readable to do three things in three statements than in one.